# Pandas read CSV with embedded JSON into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, json-normalize

I need to read in a CSV file with Pandas and one of the columns in the CSV is JSON data.  Once I bring in the file, however, the JSON is corrupted(?) and I cannot use `json_normalize()` on it.

I can't attach the file, but here is some sample code that demonstrates the problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'location_id':[1,2,3], 'visits':[{"ABCD":9,"DEFG":8,"ASDF":6},
                                                    {"XYZR":4,"ABCD":4},
                                                    {"ASDF":4}]})
pd.json_normalize(df.visits)
# OUTPUTS THE NORMALIZED JSON JUST FINE

df.to_csv('test_visits.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test_visits.csv')
pd.json_normalize(df2.visits)

# RESULTS IN ERROR:
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Is there something I'm missing in the `read_csv()` that keeps the JSON usable?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The issue is, the `'visits'` column is `str` type (e.g. `'{"ABCD":9,"DEFG":8,"ASDF":6}'`).
- When loading the csv with [`.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), use the `converters` parameter to apply [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to the `'visits'` column, which will convert the `str` to a `dict`.

  - `converters`: *Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels.*

```py
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

# load the csv using the converters parameter with literal_eval
df2 = pd.read_csv('test_visits.csv', converters={'visits': literal_eval})

# normalize the visits, join it to location_id and drop the visits column
df2 = df2.join(pd.json_normalize(df2.visits)).drop(columns=['visits'])

# display(df)
   location_id  ABCD  DEFG  ASDF  XYZR
0            1   9.0   8.0   6.0   NaN
1            2   4.0   NaN   NaN   4.0
2            3   NaN   NaN   4.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [77]: df = pd.DataFrame({'location_id':[1,2,3], 'visits':[{"ABCD":9,"DEFG":8,"ASDF":6},
    ...:                                                     {"XYZR":4,"ABCD":4},
    ...:                                                     {"ASDF":4}]})

In [78]: df
Out[78]:
   location_id                             visits
0            1  {'ABCD': 9, 'DEFG': 8, 'ASDF': 6}
1            2             {'XYZR': 4, 'ABCD': 4}
2            3                        {'ASDF': 4}

In [79]: pd.json_normalize(df["visits"])
Out[79]:
   ABCD  DEFG  ASDF  XYZR
0   9.0   8.0   6.0   NaN
1   4.0   NaN   NaN   4.0
2   NaN   NaN   4.0   NaN
```

This is happening because once you write to csv and read it from csv, pandas reads it as string. Hence, when you try to normalize it, it will throw error saying `str` object has no attribute `values` because it's not a json object

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to use `literal_eval` as described in the comments above and got the str converted back to JSON.  Your explanation was helpful.